# javax.mail with HTML message + attachment not sending HTML message but sending attachment

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, mailing

I am using this code to send `text/html` content along with `attachment` but it's only sending attachment.

```
    package com.maling.sendmail;

    import java.util.Properties;
    import javax.activation.DataHandler;
    import javax.activation.DataSource;
    import javax.activation.FileDataSource;
    import javax.mail.Message;
    import javax.mail.Session;
    import javax.mail.Transport;
    import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
    import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

    public class sendmail {

        boolean flag = false;
        String from = "myemailid@gmail.com";
        String password = "Pa**w*rd";
        String filename = "D:\\myfile.pdf";

        public boolean sendMail(String email_id_of_recipients) {
            System.out.println("into maling utility......");
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
            props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
            props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
            Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
                    new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                        @Override
                        protected javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                            return new javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication(from, password);
                        }
                    });
            try {
                String text = "<h1>Hello My html formeted message</h1>";
                String to = email_id_of_recipients;
                MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
                message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
                message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(to));
                message.setSubject("Myresume");
                message.setText(text, "utf-8", "html");
                message.setContent(text, "text/html; charset=utf-8");
                DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
                message.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
                message.setFileName(filename);
                Transport.send(message);

                flag = true;
                System.out.println("end of utility");
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println(ex);
            }

            return flag;
        }

    }
```

How should i make it right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need a [multipart message](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Multipart_messages) to send both a text and an attachment. This code should work:

```
String text = "<h1>Hello My HTML formatted message</h1>";
String to = email_id_of_recipients;
MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(to));
message.setSubject("My resume");
// message.setText(text, "utf-8", "html");

MimeBodyPart textPart = new MimeBodyPart();
textPart.setContent(text, "text/html; charset=utf-8");

DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename);
Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart("mixed");
multipart.addBodyPart(textPart);
multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
message.setContent(multipart);

Transport.send(message);
```

Comment: Sorry to say sir but, i followed your foot printed and replace my code by the code given by you and add additional packages those were required  but the result is still same as it was.

Comment: You're right - you'll need another `MimeBodyPart`. I updated my answer, please check again.